# GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am getting an issue when checking user paypal subscription details:

Below is the error code I am getting:

```
   {
    "name": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The specified resource does not exist.",
    "debug_id": "e811654b3ae54",
    "details": [
        {
            "issue": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
            "description": "Requested resource ID was not found."
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
            "rel": "information_link",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails is part of the classic API which uses NVP/SOAP.  This looks like you must be hitting the REST endpoints.  Can you provide an example of the request you are sending and the URL you are sending it to?

Comment: $curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-XD8N0561FXEL",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer A21AAGRe201sENCPvPPW6i4FTReWv2jLRTngffSjtqkaJpzNQceqXYAnn2jQSg29IVkwPJiUfEbc5LGsob5JcyWgwTG8ZmdeA",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded,application/json",
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

Comment: Yeah, it seems you're trying to call Classic APIs against the REST API endpoints.  That's not going to work.  Did you create the profiles with Classic or REST?

Comment: i have made profile by redirecting to paypal .once payment completed its redirected back to my site.

Comment: Yes, but which APIs are you using for creating the profile?  Classic or REST?

Comment: i have used a form with action url is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr. i think its classic. i have send all profile information through this form in this acttion url.

Comment: That is a PayPal Standard endpoint.  You're a bit all over the place.  If you want the easiest thing, go to www.paypal.com/buttons and build a Standard button there.  If you want to use the API, I would start [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/).